# Windows API Establishing an Event

Tags: c++, windows, api, event-handling

So to make things clear, I'll just state that there are three different ways to develop windows app through c++.

1. Windows API. This is the fundamental interface and most laborious.
2. MFC
3. Windows Form with CLR

So yes, I want to do this the hard way, the windows API way. I already understand the basics and have a working program.

My problem is this:

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
   rect2.top += 10;
   rect2.bottom += 10;
   InvalidateRect(hWnd, NULL, TRUE);
   return 0;
```

I only know that a key is down and have no idea how to be a little specific, perhaps the down key. Also how do you manually establish an event which only takes a double click in MFC or CLR. I hope you guys will answer and thank you.

Comment: All messages get params, namely _wParam_ and _lParam_

Comment: When using this API, you need to look up things **a lot**. [`WM_KEYDOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx) gives you a push towards [Virtual Key Codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx). As for window messages, Raymond Chen points out in his blog that (and why) `WPARAM` is usually used for integer values, whereas `LPARAM` for pointers, which eases remembering a bit.

Comment: You checked MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646280(v=vs.85).aspx `wparam` contains key code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an overview and some examples in "[Using Keyboard Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646268%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)". As stated in a comment, processing keyboard events might not be obvious, depending on what you want exactly. A list of virtual key code is available [here](http://www.kbdedit.com/manual/low_level_vk_list.html).

```
case WM_KEYDOWN: 
    switch (wParam) 
    { 
        case VK_LEFT: 

            // Process the LEFT ARROW key. 

            break; 

        case VK_RIGHT: 

            // Process the RIGHT ARROW key. 

            break; 

        case VK_UP: 

            // Process the UP ARROW key. 

            break; 

        case VK_DOWN: 

            // Process the DOWN ARROW key. 

            break; 

        // Process other non-character keystrokes. 

        default: 
            break; 
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I swear I searched alot, I just simply lack the term cause I'm still new to the windows api stuff. Anyway I'm downloading the whole documentation of c++ right now (560mb) so that should help.

Comment: Ok, one more thing, what is the difference between wParam and lParam?

Comment: @JoeyArnoldAndres, Searching for `WM_KEYDOWN` and following relevant does the trick. Both WPARAM and LPARAM are the same in 32-bit apps, but LPARAM used to be a long, where WPARAM was a word. Searching `Windows Data Types` gives a good page on stuff like that. As I mentioned before, too, Raymond Chen explained WPARAM vs. LPARAM pretty well once in [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/25/55850.aspx). But when you say whole documentation, do you mean all of the Window API documentation? If so, where can I get that?

Comment: OH for the API documentation, I downloaded it through the Visual Studio Release Canditate 2012. They "Microsoft Help" in that thingis awesome, you can pick a documentation you can download, and, it happens that Windows development is one of it.